# Can I write a Visual Basic Interpreter?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I am planning to write an interpreter (sort of an implementation) of Visual Basic (or more precisely, Visual Basic for Applications - VBA) on my own. I could not find anywhere what's the license of the language. Are only it's implementations proprietary?

Answer (score 2):

Given a proper and correct BNF ([Backuss Naur Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)) that describes the syntax of the language, you can completely write an interpreter without any knowledge of Microsoft's' nor anyone else's interpreters. Nor would you need to know anything about how their interpreters work.

Your parser, lexer and other constructs must not infringe on software patents in force, but that should be fairly easy to conform to.

I write computer language parsers for a living, and I do not need to reverse engineer any existing code in order to do things like this.

Since the language in question has public documentation about it's syntax, I believe you can write a parser for it even if the language itself is copyrighted, because you are not yourself changing it. You are simply writing computer code that instructs a computer what to do when it sees such a language.

There are computer programs today in use that recognize writing, street signs, roadways, etc. in order to instruct a self-driving car how to navigate a roadway. Think of Visual Basic in this case to be what the computer is observing and acting upon. It's simply navigating the Visual Basic language.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that VBA, given its background does not have an (E)BNF representation. Still, it wouldn't matter. Two software programs are not considered copies merely because they do the same thing. Even doing the same thing in the same way may not be infringement, when that's the logical solution for that case.

Comment: @MSalters - good point. But it shouldn't be too hard to construct a BNF for it.

Comment: I actually meant that I suspect VBA is not context-free, and therefore it's impossible to construct a BNF.

Comment: Yet, the language itself has to be deterministic. And if so, there must be a way to construct a fairly accurate one. I myself wouldn't want to write a parser for it.

Comment: Deterministic is unrelated to context-free. I mean that you cannot create an BNF grammar at all (which probably could be automated), but you need to manually create an explicit context-dependent grammar. This grammar would have a legally complex status - it's unclear whether it qualifies for copyright protection, because there's no obvious category in which it would fall. And I'm fairly certain not all products of human creativity are copyrightable, fragrances being a well-known edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic for Applications is almost surely protected by copyright, so absent an exception to copyright law, you may not legally make a work derivative of it.

An "interpreter" sounds to me like a derivative work, but without knowing what you mean by this in this situation, it is hard to know if it would constitute a derivative work or not.

The purpose for which the ultimate product is to be used is also relevant.

Comment: The interpreter is the thing that runs visual basic code. It translates the visual basic code into machine code, if you will.  My understanding is that reverse engineering something by examining how it works and creating something that works the same doesn't violate the copyright.

Comment: I am not willing to reverse engineer anything, only use the publicly avaible Documentation

Comment: @phoog Ah. I learn new things every day. Given your comment and the follow up comment by Nirtam, however, I'm not at all confident that even knowing that I could accurately apply the general legal principles accurately to these facts. If I were a judge, I'd want to hear expert testimony and legal arguments from both sides before making a decision as this is not a plain vanilla case for the derivative works provisions of copyright law.

Comment: @Nirtam by "reverse engineer" I mean to determine how the thing works without decompiling the compiled code or obtaining the source code.  I believe that it is permissible to make reference to public documentation.  But the basic principle is that you create something that, when given the same input, yields the same result.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design.  ohwilleke: you may find the examples given in the Wikipedia article to be informative.  Nirtam: surely in the BIOS example cited, the programmers must have made use of the documentation.